# Using js, is it possible to prevent a text selection from extending when shift-clicking elsewhere

Tags: javascript, firefox

Please do not report this question as a duplicate. I have seen similar questions on stackoverflow, but they don't answer my specific need.

I have some text selected and highlighted on a web page and I'd like to be able to shift-click away from the selected text without extending the selection of text.

I have created a function that sets the variable shiftkey to true whenever the shift key is pressed and I have another function that gets called on a mouse click. The latter function tests if the shiftkey var is set to true to determine if I have a shift-click event. If so, I thought e.preventDefault(); 
would prevent extending the selected text, but it doesn't!

Using

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.userSelect = "none";
```

followed by

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

and finally

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.userSelect = "auto";
```

doesn't work either!

Any ideas how this can be made to work?

Comment: If you have seen similar questions here, then add links to those that are closest to your question, and explain why they don't answer your question.

Comment: The proposed answers I have seen apply the css rule user-select: none to an element, class or id. That's not what I want to do. I'd like to still be able to get the original text selection without extending it when I shift-click away for the selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable text selection while pressing 'shift'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527751/disable-text-selection-while-pressing-shift)

Comment: I didn't say you should tell what they did, but that you should add links to them to your question. I marked your question as a possible duplicate, because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529206/1960455) does exactly what you are asking, prevents further selection while the shift key is down.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem by reading [this page about the selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object and [this page about the range object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range).

I had to assign the original selection to a range and save it to a variable.

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
```

Then, after shift-clicking, the selection would get extended so I would have to empty the selection using either:

```
sel.empty();
```

or

```
sel.removeAllRanges();
```

Thereafter, I could add the original saved range to the empty selection using:

```
sel.addRange(range);
```