# prevent shift highlight bubbling out of jQuery-UI dialog?

Tags: datatables, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

I have created a form-based web application with jQuery-UI and DataTables v1.9 ... etc.
Recently, I added a new feature to allow shift-click to highlight multiple row in DataTables for advanced operations. I know that shift-click will highlight texts, but this time it works unexpected to me, take [jQuery-UI demo pag](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)e as example:

[text highlight goes outside dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnV7i.png)

When shift-click upward instead of downward in DataTables, much more texts were highlighted. I have applied JavaScript on tbody of DataTables to hide such behavior from users for now:

```
$("table#data_table1 > tbody")[0].onselectstart = function() { return false; }
```

Actually, I just want to prevent the highlight bubbling out of jQuery-UI dialog, how do I modify the JavaScript to stop the bubbling?

[It should be allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVLyv.png)

[It should also allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlIoi.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to prevent text selection while pressing 'shift'? If that is the case, you could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527751/disable-text-selection-while-pressing-shift).

Comment: It is not "disable", the images behind the links shows the current situation. I would provide mock up of actual form in my system once I removed any sensitive information on it.